# How do i fix this render problem for showing costraintlayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I installed Android Studio 4.0 and used  `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6` to use motion editor, then, when I deleted `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3`, it showed me a render problem error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams$Table
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:2521)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1741)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:479)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1125)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:348)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:404)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:678)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: did you tried syncing your project with gradle ?

Comment: You tried invalidate and restart application after update your A.S version? Go to File -> Invalidate and Restart